# Discord.js bot commands not working. How to solve?

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a bot with discord.js. It shows there are no errors, and goes online and runs perfectly. However, when I try to run a command, the bot doesn't say anything, not even an error message. My code is here:

```js
const discord = require('discord.js');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
const bot = new discord.Client();
const PREFIX = "//";

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('CherryBot is online!');

})

bot.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.equals(bot.user)) return;

  if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;

  var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split("");

  switch (args[0].toLowerCase()) {
    case "ping":

      message.channel.sendMessage("Pong!")
      break;

    case "cherry":
      image(message);

      break;
  }
});

function image(message) {

  var options = {
    url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + "cherry fruit"
    , method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "text/html",
      "User-Agent": "Chrome"
    }
  };

  request(options, function (error, response, responseBody) {
    if (error) {
      return;
    }

    $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

    var links = $(".image a.link");

    var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

    console.log(urls);

    if (!urls.length) {

      return;
    }

    // Send result
    message.channel.send(urls[Math.floor(Math.random() * urls.length)]);
  });
}
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using discord.js version v12.17.0 @Syntle

Comment: `Channel.sendMessage` is deprecated, use `Channel.send` instead. If you're watching a tutorial or something, make sure that it isn't old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you defined `args` wrong, you need to `split()` using spaces, `slice()` the `prefix` and `trim()` whitespaces like so:

```js
const args = message.content
          .slice(PREFIX.length) // gets rid of the prefix
          .trim() // removes whitespaces
          .split(/ +/g) // splits using spaces
```

Then you need to use `send()` instead of `sendMessage()` since it's deprecated.

```js
case "ping":
    message.channel.send("Pong!")
break;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome and welcome to SO. If an answer solves your question then accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked and that the question was answered

Answer (score 0):

you error is simple, in `var args = ...` you used `split` to split every character. To work you need to split just spaces. Just add a space in `split` function.

```js
var args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
```

Also, `message.channel.sendMessage` doesn't work anymore, you need to use `message.channel.send` instead.

I did that changes and your bot works perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer as correct by using the tick mark next to it, to let peoples knows that is correct